# How to determine scale to increase sprite width to screen width

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to achieve something similar to [How to increase (animate) the width of the square on both ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768415/how-to-increase-animate-the-width-of-the-square-on-both-ends) in Unity. How can I determine the scale by which to increase the width (of the sprite) for it to fill the whole screen width?

**UPDATE**

Below is the Swift code for I implemented for expanding the sprite width to take the full screen width:

```
       func expandEnemy () {

         spritePosBeforeScaleX = CGPointMake((enemy?.sprite.position.x)!, (enemy?.sprite.anchorPoint.y)!)

         enemy?.sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake((enemy?.sprite.position.x)! / self.size.width, (enemy?.sprite.anchorPoint.y)!)
         let enemyScalingAction = SKAction.scaleXTo(self.size.width / (enemy?.sprite.size.width)!, duration: 1.0)
         enemy!.sprite.runAction(enemyScalingAction)

         delay(0.1)  
         {
            center = CGPointMake(enemy!.sprite.size.width / 2 - (enemy!.sprite.size.width * enemy!.sprite.anchorPoint.x), enemy!.sprite.size.height / 2 - (enemy!.sprite.size.height * enemy!.sprite.anchorPoint.y))
            enemy!.sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: enemy!.sprite.size, center: center)
         }
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Maybe there is another way to accomplish this

Comment: @Programmer I want to accomplish what was done in the link in unity - extend the width of a square (game object) on both ends till it occupies the width of a screen. KnightOfDragon's approach  was to scale the width to give it the effect of animation. I wanted to use the same approach, but I am open to another approach since I just realised that this approach would have issues with sprites that have more than one colour since they would stretch also, Eg (a checked block wouldn't look to good when stretched in a similar way). I hope this gives a better idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Programmer I'll look through, I should have a sample where I implemented the solution in Swift. I'll update the question once I find it. But as I mentioned, there are issues with the stretching width approach because it defaces sprites that have more than one colour. Maybe another approach could be taking a sprite, which is a strip of the original sprite (Eg. if the sprite is 50x50, a 5x50 portion of the original sprite) this would be repeated for an animation at both ends of the original sprite till the whole width is covered. Please let me know what you think about this approach.

Comment: @Programmer I just updated the question with the Swift implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the aspect ratio of the screen and the size of the object with the SpriteRenderer. You need to scale up the gameobject that holds the spriterenderer by a factor where you take these into consideration.

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SpriteToScreen : MonoBehaviour {
public float sprw = 256f;
public float sprh = 256f;
float unitspp = 100f;
public float scrw = 0f;
public float scrh = 0f;
public float aspect = 0f;
public float spr_aspect = 1f;
public float factorY = 0.017578125f;
public void Update(){
    scrw = Screen.width;
    scrh = Screen.height;
    aspect = scrw / scrh;
    unitspp = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.pixelsPerUnit;
    sprw = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.size.x * unitspp;
    sprh = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.size.y * unitspp;
    spr_aspect = sprw / sprh;
    this.transform.localScale = new Vector3( (1152f / sprh * aspect) / spr_aspect,
        1152f / sprh, 
        1 );
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scale `Image` of an UI in x-axis full screen. Just get the `RectTransform` then modify the `sizeDelta` property of it to the Screen size of the device or the size of the `Canvas`.

The function below can scale Unity UI Image in x, y or both x and y axis full screen. The `Image` to scale must be under `Canvas`. Assign a `Sprite` to the `Source Image` of the `Image` component the code below should work.

//Attach the UI Image to scacle in the Editor here

```
public GameObject image;
```

**To Scale**:

Scale in X-axis Full Screen in **3** seconds:

```
StartCoroutine(scaleToFullScreen(image, 0, 3f));
```

Scale in Y-axis Full Screen in **3** seconds:

```
StartCoroutine(scaleToFullScreen(image, 1, 3f));
```

Scale in X-axis AND Y-axis Full Screen in **3** seconds:

```
StartCoroutine(scaleToFullScreen(image, 2, 3f));
```

**The Scale function**:

```
bool isScaling = false;
IEnumerator scaleToFullScreen(GameObject imageToScale, int scaleType, float byTime)
{
    if (isScaling)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    if (scaleType < 0 || scaleType > 2)
    {
        Debug.Log("Invalid ScaleType. Valid Scale Types X:0,  Y:1,  XandY:3");
        yield break;
    }
    isScaling = true;

    Canvas canvas = imageToScale.GetComponentInParent<Canvas>();
    float x, y;

    if (canvas != null)
    {
        x = canvas.pixelRect.width;
        y = canvas.pixelRect.height;
    }
    else
    {
        x = Screen.width;
        y = Screen.height;
    }

    RectTransform rect = imageToScale.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    if (rect == null)
    {
        rect = imageToScale.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    //Center the position of the image so that it will be resized equally
    rect.anchoredPosition3D = new Vector3(0, 0, rect.anchoredPosition3D.z);


    //The default Size
    Vector2 originalScale = rect.sizeDelta;

    //The new scale we want to scale texture to
    Vector2 newScale = originalScale;

    if (scaleType == 0)
    {
        newScale.x = x;
    }
    else if (scaleType == 1)
    {
        newScale.y = y;
    }
    else if (scaleType == 2)
    {
        newScale.x = x;
        newScale.y = y;
    }


    float counter = 0;
    while (counter < byTime)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        rect.sizeDelta = Vector2.Lerp(originalScale, newScale, counter / byTime);
        yield return null;
    }
    isScaling = false;
}
```