# Issues scaling sprite width to screen width

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

Practically I am trying to achieve not too different from what was done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768415/how-to-increase-animate-the-width-of-the-square-on-both-ends) (scale a sprite regardless of it's position on the screen till it fills the screen width). Please see my code below:

```
      if touch?.tapCount == 2  {  
        self.view?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        mySprite?.sprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: (mySprite?.sprite.position.x)! / self.size.width, y: (mySprite?.sprite.anchorPoint.y)!)
        let scaleSpriteAction = SKAction.scaleX(to: self.size.width / (mySprite?.sprite.size.width)!, duration: 0.1)
        mySprite!.sprite.run(scaleSpriteAction)

        delay(0.1)  {
            centerPoint = CGPoint(x: mySprite!.sprite.size.width / 2 - (mySprite!.sprite.size.width * mySprite!.sprite.anchorPoint.x), y: mySprite!.sprite.size.height / 2 - (mySprite!.sprite.size.height * mySprite!.sprite.anchorPoint.y))

            mySprite!.sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:    mySprite!.sprite.size, center: centerPoint)
            mySprite!.sprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = mySpriteCategory
            mySprite!.sprite.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

        }
     }
```

The sprite expands but it doesn't always fill the whole screen. From my observation it happens more frequently when the sprite is closer to the left or right ends of the screen. After logging the sprite positions before and after the delay and realizing they were different, I disabled user interaction but that didn't change the anything.
The delay ensures that the `physicsBody` also scales to the full screen width.

What could be causing the sprite expansion inconsistency (not always filling the screen width) and how can I get it to fill the whole width every time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a disproportionate scaling:

```
SKAction.scaleX(to: self.size.width / mySprite!.sprite.size.width, duration: 0.1)
SKAction.scaleY(to: self.size.height / mySprite!.sprite.size.height, duration: 0.1)
```

1 • Assign your physicsBody before you do anything else.
2 • Anchor point should be CGPoint(0.5, 0.5)
3 • You also need to run an SKAction moving your image to the center of the screen

If you want proportionate scaling, so the image stops when it hits any edge, you'll want to keep track of the screen ratio and image ratio.