# Swift : How to adjust texture/image to physicsBody's position after changing anchor point?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sktexture, anchorpoint

After changing the anchor point on my `SKTexture`, my texture now has the desired anchor point, but my physicsBody does not. Before i changed the anchor point they were happy together at the same position.

[visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/151Rv.png)

This is the only code i wrote changing the anchor points : 
**rightDrop.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)**

How can I move the physicsBody so that it has the same anchor point as the texture?

Comment: Texture doesn't have an anchorPoint. anchorPoint is a property found on a node and it defines how the texture is drawn relatively to the node's position. It is a visual propety and it has nothing with a physics body as you have already experienced. Now, you probably doing something wrong (wrong logic), but you may try to create a new physics body using an initializer which has a center parameter to achieve what you want.

Comment: Still, I would say using anchorPoint here is wrong approach. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can specify the center point of your physics body, look at the inits:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody

Comment: I have to be able to get this to work correctly, and have abandoned anchorpoints a while back @Knight0fDragon, and jennifer, and WW

Comment: What? @Fluidity. Just move the center point of your physics body to where your anchor point needs to be

Comment: It can only be done on the init of a body

Comment: @Knight0fDragon hmm I thought it was bugged .. last time I tried I couldn't get it to work

Comment: I have an answer on here solving this problem with all the math,  I havent had time to look for it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon that would be cool. because I've gone through about ten playgrounds a while back and 4-5 posts and couldn't get it to work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34584013/270964

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I got it working using your code and some extra help from a colleague! I had to change the anchorPoints of the scene as well, after some tidying up the scene it looks all good! Thanks! :)

Comment: @JenniferAndrén, no problem,  just an FYI there is a small slack group I am a part of that has a few developers that play around with sprite kit, if you want more info feel free to email me at knight0fdragon@gmail.com